# Render Camera picture to texture

Tags: android

Is there a way to bind camera picture to shader?

I set up the camera preview via:

```
// Create shader and GL program
_texture = new SurfaceTexture( _texName );
_camera = Camera.open();
_camera.setPreviewTexture( texture );
_camera.startPreview(); // What does start preview do internally?
```

When a new picture is available I do:

```
_texture.updateTexImage(); // Should bind to GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OS
GLES20.glViewport( 0, 0, _surfaceWidth, _surfaceHeight );
GLES20.glBindFramebuffer( GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _framebuffers[0] );
GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D( GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, _texName, 0);
```

P.S. the original code contains error checking

Comment: I think you can't bind GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES as render target. But what you can do is use it via samplerExternalOES in shaders - rather similarly as you use sampler2D too.

Comment: I was looking at something similar in order to use glReadPixels to read the SurfaceTexture data from the GPU. I assume, @harism, that your solution would involve explicitly drawing a rectangle textured with the GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES texture, and then reading that out instead? Can I at least write it to an invisible frame buffer or is that not supported either?